# want to Print Counter on boxes on how many boxes program prints. for OS X ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

So i have following Code thats responsible for drawing the boxes with takes input from user of PanelWidth and Panelheight which is per box and it draws with two colors. I want to be able Print counter on this as in rows its 1,2,3,4,5,6  as well as on columns its A1, B1, C1....  how can i achieve this is for OS X app written in Objective C

this is what this code [prints now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sXi3.png)  this is what i want it to [print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PF4AM.png)

```
//screen drawing

for (int r=0; r < 2*row; r++) {
    long int positionVer = (panelHeight*r);

    for (int i=0; i < 2*col; i++) {
        long int positionHor = (panelWidth*i);

        NSRect col1= NSMakeRect(positionHor,positionVer, panelWidth, panelHeight);

        if (_bgEnable) {
            if( (r+i) %2 )
            {
                [rectColor2 set];
            }
            else {
                [rectColor set];
            }

        }


        else{
            [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0.0 alpha:0.0] setFill];
            NSRectFillUsingOperation(col1, NSCompositeSourceAtop);
        }

        NSRectFill (col1);

        if (_BoarderEnable) {
        [boarderColor set];
        NSFrameRectWithWidth ( col1, _boarderWidth);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this. Here's one. This uses a custom view to do the drawing (it's up to you to create the view and assign the values). The drawing is from the bottom up so to get the numbering correct, you have to start with the total rows then subtract the current row (and for user-friendliness, add 1 to the column number). Since ASCII characters are sequential, you can start at 65 (A) and increment from there. You can also update the text attributes and allow the user to further customize as desired. I'm sure there are some optimizations that could be made (or a better way to do this overall) but this should get you going.

```
@interface BoxView : NSView
@property (assign) NSInteger columnCount;
@property (assign) NSInteger rowCount;
@property (assign) CGFloat width;
@property (assign) CGFloat height;
@property (strong) NSColor *c0;
@property (strong) NSColor *c1;
@property (assign) BOOL drawBorder;
@end

@implementation BoxView

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSFont labelFontOfSize:12.0], NSFontAttributeName,
                                [NSColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                nil];
    CGFloat x = 0.0, y = 0.0;
    BOOL useColor0 = YES;
    for (NSInteger r = 0; r < self.rowCount; r++) {
        for (NSInteger c = 0; c < self.columnCount; c++) {
            NSRect box = NSMakeRect(x, y, self.width, self.height);
            NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:box];
            [(useColor0 ? self.c0 : self.c1) set];
            [path fill];
            if (self.drawBorder) {
                [[NSColor blackColor] setStroke];
                [path stroke];
            }
            NSString *arrow = nil;
            if (r == 0) {
                if (self.rowCount % 2) {
                    if (c == (self.columnCount - 1)) arrow = @"∅";
                } else if (c == 0) {
                    arrow = @"∅";
                }
            }
            if (!arrow) {
                if ((self.rowCount - r) % 2) {
                    arrow = ((c == (self.columnCount - 1)) ? @"↓" : @"→");
                } else {
                    arrow = ((c == 0) ? @"↓" : @"←");
                }
            }
            NSString *label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%ld %@", (char)(65 + c), (self.rowCount - r), arrow];
            [label drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint((x + 5.0), (y + self.height - 16.0)) withAttributes:attributes];
            x += self.width;
            useColor0 = !useColor0;
        }
        x = 0.0;
        y += self.height;
        useColor0 = (r % 2);
    }
}

@end
```

You can download a demo app here: [BoxesDemo.zip](http://www.jonn8.com/dist/BoxesDemo.zip)

Comment: Thank you SO much for this code !! I really really appreciate your help for going this length.  i would love to chat with you if you don't mind please email me at rit3sh7 at gmail if you don't mind ?